PgAdmin autocompletion in other schemas
Can anyone advise me on how to make the autocomplete in PgAdmin not only work (properly) in the public schema? Let's say I have a schema called sandbox and I'm lazy to constantly type the schema prefix in front of the object names. The solution to this is to use search_path (with appropriate grants of course), but it doesn't seem to solve the autocomplete without schema prefix. Another problem is that when I use the schema prefix, the database objects appear in the autocomplete list (regardless of whether I have previously set search_path), but not when using table aliases (even though the public schema does autocomplete with aliases)! Does anyone know a solution to this? Thanks in advance for your tips!
Which I have already tried:

SET search_path TO sandbox;

Check GRANTs for the given user.

Check pgadmin autocomplete settings.


What I expect:
The autocomplete should work the same way under a different schema (in this case "sandbox") as under the public schema

For my part, I've given up on doing this in PgAdmin for the time being. I have tried DBeaver and it does everything I missed in PgAdmin. However, I'll leave the request here, it would be nicer if there was a solution in PgAdmin. Maybe someone knows it. Anyway, a big gold star for DBeaver!
